# onitemclick is not working in listview dialog

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-emulator, android-listview

on click item is not working inside dialog..

Description: i have one print button when i click that button a dialog will appear which contains  listview using adapter.. when i click on listview row it must go to other activity.. But problem is onitemclick is not working in listview dialog..

thank u in advance.

WorkDetailView.java

```
 printbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.barcodePrintButton);
    printbutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        private Context context = WorkDetailView.this;

        /**
         * 
         * Description: barcodePrintButton onClick to ServiceManager.callPrintService
         * 
         */
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

                dialog = new Dialog(context);
                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialoglistview);
                dialog.setTitle("Print Dialog");

                listviewDialog = (ListView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialogList);
                dataDialogAdapter = new WorkDetailDialogAdapter(context, sampleDetailsArray);
                listviewDialog.setAdapter(dataDialogAdapter);
                listviewDialog.setClickable(true);
                listviewDialog.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view, int position, long id) {
                    Log.i("selectedAdapter", "selectedAdapter"+ position);

                    Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.ENCODE");
                    intent.putExtra("ENCODE_DATA", patient.getMrnNumber());
                    intent.putExtra("ENCODE_FORMAT", "CODE_128");
                //  intent.putExtra("ENCODE_SHOW_CONTENTS", false);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    Toast.makeText(WorkDetailView.this, "Printing Barcode Result", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
            });

                dialog.show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: does it run into this line,Log.i("selectedAdapter", "selectedAdapter"+ position);

Comment: no boss.. onitemclick is not working

Comment: `public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
         // Do something with the selection
    }
});` select your item based on the selection of item above and then pass intent - I can give you a better example in a little while - but try this

Comment: @Rao's ..i know its very late,but how did you get over this issue, because im stuck on the same problem right now? can you please explain?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to change the type of onClickListener to Dialog.onClickListener?

```
android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener ocl =   new Dialog.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Place `dialog.show()` before `listviewDialog.setClickable(true)`

Comment: what is actually happeneing? LOGCAT?

Comment: nothing is displaying in Logcat.. bcoz onitemclick is not working.. its just appear like dialog.. i will add a images..so u may get some idea.

Answer (score 0):

try this way to build your dialog

```
LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialoglistview, 
    (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.root_id_in_dialoglistview_xml_tree));
dialog = AlertDialog.Builder(this).setTitle("Print Dialog").setView(layout);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Button btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

        btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                showdialog();
            }});
private void showdialog() {
        listDialog = new Dialog(this);
        listDialog.setTitle("Select Item");
        LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View v = li.inflate(R.layout.list_view, null, false);
        listDialog.setContentView(v);
        listDialog.setCancelable(true);

        final ListView list1 = (ListView) listDialog.findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        String array[] = {"1","2","3"};

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapt = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.group, array);
        list1.setAdapter(adapt);
        listDialog.show();

        list1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
                System.out.println(position);
            }
        });
    }
```